# Why do function composition and application have a dependent implementation in Agda?

Tags: agda

Why do function composition (`∘`) and application (`$`) have the implementation as available in https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Function.agda#L74-L76?
Copied here for convenience:

```
_∘_ : ∀ {a b c}
        {A : Set a} {B : A → Set b} {C : {x : A} → B x → Set c} →
        (∀ {x} (y : B x) → C y) → (g : (x : A) → B x) →
        ((x : A) → C (g x))
f ∘ g = λ x → f (g x)

_∘'_ : ∀ {a b c} {A : Set a} {B : Set b} {C : Set c} →
         (B → C) → (A → B) → (A → C)
f ∘' g = λ x → f (g x)

_$_ : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : A → Set b} →
      ((x : A) → B x) → ((x : A) → B x)
f $ x = f x

_$'_ : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : Set b} →
       (A → B) → (A → B)
f $' x = f x
```

I initially thought the rationale behind this was that `$` would be able to handle higher order types that `$'` wouldn't be able to handle. For example, consider A=Nat, B=List, f is *::*, where B depends on A. But after a lot of testing, I couldn't come up with an example that would show that the implementation of `$'` is not sufficient. What scenarios does `$` handle that `$'` isn't able to handle? (Similarly, what scenarios does `∘` handle that `∘'` doesn't?

```
open import Agda.Builtin.Nat public
open import Agda.Primitive public

--data List {a} (A : Set a) : Set a where
--  []  : List A
--  _∷_ : (x : A) (xs : List A) → List A

data Vec {a} (A : Set a) : Nat → Set a where
  []  : Vec A zero
  _∷_ : ∀ {n} (x : A) (xs : Vec A n) → Vec A (suc n)

tail : ∀ {a n} {A : Set a} → Vec A (suc n) → Vec A n
tail (x ∷ s) = s

_$_ : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : A → Set b} →
      ((x : A) → B x) → ((x : A) → B x)
f $ x = f x

_$'_ : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : Set b} →
       (A → B) → (A → B)
f $' x = f x

_∘_ : ∀ {a b c}
        {A : Set a} {B : A → Set b} {C : {x : A} → B x → Set c} →
        (∀ {x} (y : B x) → C y) → (g : (x : A) → B x) →
        ((x : A) → C (g x))
f ∘ g = λ x → f (g x)

_∘'_ : ∀ {a b c} {A : Set a} {B : Set b} {C : Set c} →
         (B → C) → (A → B) → (A → C)
f ∘' g = λ x → f (g x)

Vecc : ∀ {a} → Nat → (A : Set a) → (Set a)
Vecc x y = Vec y x

data Pair {a b} (A : Set a) (B : A → Set b) : Set (a ⊔ b) where
  _,_ : (x : A) → (y : B x) → Pair A B

-- Dependent Pair attempt
--fst : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : A → Set b} → Pair A B → A
--fst (a , b) = a
--
--f : Pair Nat $' Vec Nat
--f = _,_ zero $' []
--
--g : Pair (Pair Nat $' Vec Nat) $' λ x → Nat
--g = _,_ (_,_ zero $' []) $' zero

-- Some other attempt
--f : ∀ {a n} {A : Set a} → Vec A ((suc ∘' suc) n) → Vec A n
--f {a} = tail {a} ∘' tail {a}

-- Vec attempt
--f : ∀ {a} (A : Set a) → (Set a)
--f {a} = Vecc {a} (suc zero) ∘' Vecc {a} (suc zero)
--
--h = f Nat
--
--x : h
--x = (zero ∷ []) ∷ []

-- List attempt
--f : ∀ {a} (A : Set a) → (Set a)
--f {a} = List {a} ∘' List {a}
--
--g : ∀ {a} (A : Set a) → (Set a)
--g {a} = List {a} ∘ List {a}
--
--h = f Nat
--i = g Nat
--
--x : h
--x = (zero ∷ []) ∷ []
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`∘′` and `$′` don't work with dependent functions. You simply didn't try any tests with dependent functions. For `f $ x` examples, `f` must be dependent, for `f ∘ g`, either of the functions must be dependent. Example:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Vec
open import Function
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

replicate' : {A : Set} → A → (n : ℕ) → Vec A n
replicate' a n = replicate a

refl' : {A : Set}(a : A) → a ≡ a
refl' a = refl

-- fail1 : Vec ℕ 10
-- fail1 = replicate' 10 $′ 10

ok1 : Vec ℕ 10
ok1 = replicate' 10 $ 10

-- fail2 : ∀ n → replicate' 10 n ≡ replicate' 10 n
-- fail2 = refl' ∘′ replicate' 10

ok2 : ∀ n → replicate' 10 n ≡ replicate' 10 n
ok2 = refl' ∘ replicate' 10
```

Comment: Thanks. fail1 seems like a very straightforward example that I just didn't think to test. I tried dependent pairs (or so I thought). In my example, isn't (Vecc n) a dependent type since it's parameterized on the value that follows it? Why was I able to use `Vecc zero $' Vecc zero zero`?

Comment: `Vecc zero` has type `Set a → Set a`. That's a non-dependent function. Dependent functions look like `(x : A) -> B` where `x` occurs in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

One works with dependent functions, the other doesn't, as Andras Kovacs mentioned.

The important difference is that for non-dependent functions stronger proofs can be constructed. For example:

```
eq : {A B} -> f : (A -> B) -> x y : A -> x == y -> (f x) == (f y)
eq f x .x refl = refl
```

Here we can construct equality of `f x` and `f y`. But we can't do the same for dependent functions - because there is no way to prove `B x == B y`. So there is only a weaker proof that `f x` can be "cast" to `f y`.

```
transport : {A} {B : A -> Set} -> f : (x : A -> B x) -> x y : A -> x == y -> f x -> f y
transport f x .x refl fx = fx
```

(Actually, `transport` is usually defined as `B x -> B y`, not for a dependent function; but I just can't come up with a better name)